# Sharing an array with STL vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stdvector

I would like to *share* the contents of an array of doubles `a` of size `k` with one or more STL vectors `v1`, `v2`...`vn`.

The effect that I want from this shared storage is that if the underlying array gets modified the change can be observed from all the vectors that share its contents with the array.

I can do that by defining the vectors `v1`...`vn` as vectors of pointers

```
vector<double*> v1;
```

and copy the pointers `a` to `a + k` into this vector. However, I do not like that solution. I want the vectors to be a vector of doubles.

Given that you can extract the underlying pointer from a vector I am assuming one could initialize a vector with an array in such a way that the contents are shared. Would appreciate help about how to do this.

Comment: By "share" do you mean that the `v`'s have to has distinct identity because they will do separate duty somehow (maybe having other values in `[l > k]`? Is there some reason that you can't make `a` a vector and the `v` references too it?

Comment: Related and possibly duplicate:  [Converting between C++ std::vector and C array without copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733143/converting-between-c-stdvector-and-c-array-without-copying), though the answer to this part of the question is in a comment to the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: @dmckee What I want is that if an element of the array is modified all the corresponding elements of the vectors would be modified too.

Comment: BTW--So far you have told us how you think the implementation ought to work, but not what you *want to do*. The motivation might let us suggest another approach.

Comment: @dmckee I have a working implementation of a class with such an aliased storage based on arrays. I was hoping that I could have another implementation where each object stored a reference to a vector (as opposed to an array). The original implementation's constructor takes an array as an input, I was trying to preserve the input signature for the vector based implementation. What I hoped to achieve with the vector implementation is the ability to reserve and resize and the ability to exchange data cheaply with swap.

Comment: @dmckee I do realize though, that even if it were possible to give a vector view of an array it would not have solved my original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like you want to *alias* the array with a vector. So logically you want a vector of references (which doesn't work for syntactical reasons). If you really really need this feature, you can write your own `ref` wrapper class, that *behaves* exactly like an actual C++ reference, so the users of your `vn` vectors wont be able to distinguish between `vector<T>` and `vector<ref<T> >` (e.g. with `T = double`). But internally, *you* could link the items in the vectors to the items in your "master" array.

But you should have darned good reasons to do this overhead circus :)

Answer (score 2):

> Given that you can extract the underlying pointer from a vector I am assuming one could initialize a vector with an array in such a way that the contents are shared.

No, you can't do this.  The Standard Library containers always manage their own memory.

Your best option is to create the `std::vector<double>` and then use it as an array where you need to do so (via `&v[0]`, assuming the vector is non-empty).

If you just want to have the container interface, consider using `std::array` (or `boost::array` or `std::tr1::array`) or writing your own container interface to encapsulate the array.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself clearly enough. I want to go in the opposite direction. Not expose the view of an existing vector as an array, but give a vector view of an existing array. Thanks for the correction, what I ameant with extraction was returning `&v[0]`

Comment: Right.  You can't do that.  I'm saying that your best option is to try to reverse it so that the `vector` owns the data, and if that is not possible, to write your own container interface.

Answer (score 1):

OK, Standard Library containers are both *holders* of information, and *enumerators* for those elements. That is, roughly any container can be used in almost any algorithm, and at least, you can go through them using `begin()` and `end()`.

When you separate both (element holding and element enumeration), as in your case, you may consider [boost.range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/range/index.html). `boost.range` gives you a pair of iterators that delimit the extent to which algorithms will be applied, and you have the actual memory store in your array. This works mostly to read-access them, because normally, modifying the structure of the vector will invalidate the iterators. You can recreate them, though.

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed here but upvoting for the information. I am sure I will find an use for it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, as far as I know std::vector can not be given an already constructed array to use. I can not even think how that could be done since there are also the size/capacity related variables. You can possibly try to hack a way to do it using a custom allocator but I feel it will be ugly, error prone and not intuitive for future maintenance.

That said, if I may rephrase your words a bit, you are asking for multiple references to the same std::vector. I would either do just that or maybe consider using a shared_ptr to a vector.