# What container types glBufferData() can accept besides an array?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a question regarding OpenGL glBufferData() method.Can I pass the vertex data in structures like std::vector ,std::list or it must be a classic ( [] )array of numbers?

Comment: Yes: `glBufferData(target,size,&vec[0],usage)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a classic array to glBufferData() (the OpenGL API is defined in C). However, you can use std::vector<> by converting it to an array with `&v[0]` (also see [Converting between C++ std::vector and C array without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733143/converting-between-c-stdvector-and-c-array-without-copying)).

Comment: Got you ,thanks for the answer.I mistakenly assumed other types could be used as well.Saw a code snippet with a custom data type name.But then found the typedef which eventually was array of floats .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It basically needs an array. You should be able to use a `std::vector`, since it requires contiguous storage. Most others, including `std::list`, won't work. For `std::list`, it would need to be written to follow pointers, and know enough about the internals to be able to find the pointers -- but that's likely to vary between implementations, and may even change by passing different flags with the same implementation.